# How to look at a series of values stored in memory

Tags: assembly, gdb, binary-bomb

As part of a large project for a class I'm taking, I need to decipher large chunks of assembly. To judge that, I need to find the answers to different "phases" of a "bomb", via debugging that code. The goal is to not explode the bomb.

```
Dump of assembler code for function phase_2:
   0x000000000000160b <+0>:     endbr64
   0x000000000000160f <+4>:     push   %rbp
   0x0000000000001610 <+5>:     push   %rbx
   0x0000000000001611 <+6>:     sub    $0x28,%rsp
   0x0000000000001615 <+10>:    mov    %fs:0x28,%rax
   0x000000000000161e <+19>:    mov    %rax,0x18(%rsp)
   0x0000000000001623 <+24>:    xor    %eax,%eax
   0x0000000000001625 <+26>:    mov    %rsp,%rsi
   0x0000000000001628 <+29>:    callq  0x1eea <read_six_numbers>
   0x000000000000162d <+34>:    cmpl   $0x1,(%rsp)
   0x0000000000001631 <+38>:    jne    0x163d <phase_2+50>
   0x0000000000001633 <+40>:    mov    %rsp,%rbx
   0x0000000000001636 <+43>:    lea    0x14(%rsp),%rbp
   0x000000000000163b <+48>:    jmp    0x1652 <phase_2+71>
   0x000000000000163d <+50>:    callq  0x1ea8 <explode_bomb>
   //more code after this that I don't think is relevant to my question
```

After looking over this, I decided that I needed to see what was in read_six_numbers, which is as follows:

```
Dump of assembler code for function read_six_numbers:
   0x0000000000001eea <+0>:     endbr64
   0x0000000000001eee <+4>:     sub    $0x8,%rsp
   0x0000000000001ef2 <+8>:     mov    %rsi,%rdx
   0x0000000000001ef5 <+11>:    lea    0x4(%rsi),%rcx
   0x0000000000001ef9 <+15>:    lea    0x14(%rsi),%rax
   0x0000000000001efd <+19>:    push   %rax
   0x0000000000001efe <+20>:    lea    0x10(%rsi),%rax
   0x0000000000001f02 <+24>:    push   %rax
   0x0000000000001f03 <+25>:    lea    0xc(%rsi),%r9
   0x0000000000001f07 <+29>:    lea    0x8(%rsi),%r8
   0x0000000000001f0b <+33>:    lea    0x14f7(%rip),%rsi        # 0x3409
   0x0000000000001f12 <+40>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x0000000000001f17 <+45>:    callq  0x12f0 <__isoc99_sscanf@plt>
   0x0000000000001f1c <+50>:    add    $0x10,%rsp
   0x0000000000001f20 <+54>:    cmp    $0x5,%eax
   0x0000000000001f23 <+57>:    jle    0x1f2a <read_six_numbers+64>
   0x0000000000001f25 <+59>:    add    $0x8,%rsp
   0x0000000000001f29 <+63>:    retq
   0x0000000000001f2a <+64>:    callq  0x1ea8 <explode_bomb>
End of assembler dump.
```

This led to me wanting to know what was in 0x3409, which is as follows.

```
 0x00003400 6c6f776e 2075702e 00256420 25642025 lown up..%d %d %
 0x00003410 64202564 20256420 25640045 72726f72 d %d %d %d.Error
```

The answers to all the different phases are supposedly all strings. And so I thought that my answer would be the six numbers stored in the different `%d`'s However, when I typed `print 0x3409` into gdb I got 13321, which is the decimal number for 0x3409 instead of the values actually stored in memory. So what should I type in order to get the actual values in the `%d`'s?

Edit: When I typed `x 0x3409` it shot back `0x3409: 0x25206425` which I don't think is what it wanted either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, when I typed print 0x3409 into gdb I got 13321, which is the decimal number for 0x3409 instead of the values actually stored in memory.

That's what `print` command *does*.

What you apparently wanted was `examine 0x3409`, or `x 0x3409`. However, that's *not* where the numbers are -- that's where the *characters* `%`, `d`,  , `%`, `d`, etc. from the input format are.

The code *reads* six numbers (probably from `stdin`), and that's unlikely to tell you which numbers the program actually expects.